# Php copy() is not working properly

Tags: php

I'm trying to copy my uploaded file to another directory called **img** folder with following code. But it doesn't work properly. I don't know why ? can you help me plz ?

**php Code:**

```
if($image["name"] != "")
{
    //$path = PATH . DS . "uploads" . DS . "products" . DS . $id;
    $path = "../../uploads" . DS . "products" . DS . $id;

    $path2 = "img";

    if(!is_dir($path))
    {
        mkdir($path);
    }

    chmod($path, 0755);                 
     //move_uploaded_file($image["tmp_name"], $path . DS . $image["name"]);
    move_uploaded_file($image["tmp_name"], $path . DS . 
    $uploadImage);//exit;                       

    copy($uploadImage, $path2);
}
```

**Following error message show:**

```
Warning: copy(249.jpg) [function.copy]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in...
```

Comment: @Fred I set the permissions chmod($path2, 0755);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your copy function is wrong...

```
 copy($uploadImage, $path2);
```

As Spudley answer says, you have to use the full path of the image. Also, `$path2` is a directory. You have to give a name for the new copy of the image.

So, your copy function would be as follows:

```
 copy($path . DS . $uploadImage, $path2. DS . $uploadImage);
```

Try it and let us know.

Comment: Getting Error Message : copy(img/) [function.copy]: failed to open stream: Is a directory in,,,

Comment: What you get when you echo $uploadImage?

Comment: Ok, what about both paths. `echo $path . DS . $uploadImage` and `echo $path2 . DS . $uploadImage`

Comment: It's Working. GREAT!!! One more question. If i want to copy this image in same folder then what show I do now ?

Comment: You would use the same file and copy it with other name. `copy ($path2 . DS . $uploadImage, $path2. DS . $other_name)`

Comment: I'm clear it more: I've a php page called action.php(which page is running) which in "actions" directory. In this directory i've another directory called "img". Now it's copy the image to "img" directory. So If i want to copy this image to "actions" directory then what should i do now ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30851/discussion-between-luigi-siri-and-alex-mojum)

Answer (score 2):

The `copy()` function needs the full file path for the source file; you're just passing the filename, not the path.

As things stand, it's looking in the current folder for the file, not finding it, and throwing the error as a result.

From the previous line of code, it looks like your full path should be `$path . DS . $uploadImage`, so the copy command should look like this:

```
copy($path . DS . $uploadImage, $path2);
```

hope that helps.

Comment: Getting this error : Warning: copy(img) [function.copy]: failed to open stream: Is a directory in

Comment: DS means: define("DS", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

Comment: @AlexMojum - make sure that `$uploadImage` is set to something. I'm guessing it's blank. You need to set it to something (whatever name you want to give the file) before the `move_uploaded_image()` call.

Comment: what if you `echo($path . DS . $uploadImage);` ?

Comment: No I just echo $uploadImage

Comment: what do you get if you `echo($path . DS . $uploadImage);` ?? ie what is the full file it is trying to copy; so we can work out why it's saying that it's a directory.

Comment: It's now copy the image to img folder. But what should I do if I copy this image to same folder which the script page it's running ?

Comment: The copy() function don't actually need the full file path but rather just a *correct* one